# Socket.io - GET returns 404 (Not Found) (polling-xhr)

Tags: express, socket.io, phaser-framework, browser-sync

I've seen similar questions asked here, but so far I've been unable to find a solution to my problem - I may be going a bit mad now.

I'm trying to make use of **socket.io**, and have so far set up an express server and have socket.io running on the server, and on the client side (socket.io-client).

Unfortunately when I try to communicate with the server from the client side, I immediately run into repeating **404 errors**:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MU8YJvg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MU8YJvg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MU8YJvg 404 (Not Found)
...
```

Essentially my BrowserSync will run at localhost:3000 and my express/socket.io will run at localhost:8080

My **express** set up looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(http);


io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("a user connected: ", socket.id);
});

app.set("port", 8080);

// Attempt to proxy around BrowserSync
app.use(
  "/socket-io",
  proxy({
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    ws: true,
    pathRewrite: { "^/socket.io": "/" }
  })
);

http.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${http.address().port}`);
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
....
plugins: [
    definePlugin,
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: process.env.IP || "localhost",
      port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
      server: {
        baseDir: ["./", "./dist"]
      }
    })
]
...
```

**I'm using**

```
(dev-deps)
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
(deps)
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
```

I'd be really thankful for any help on this as nothing makes sense any more.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was falling into a rabbit hole of confusing myself with config.

I simplified things back to just:

**express:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
const { addPlayerIO } = require("./utils/addPlayer.io");

io.on("connection", socket => {
   console.log("a user connected: ", socket.id);
});

http.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${http.address().port}`);
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
....
plugins: [
    definePlugin,
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: process.env.IP || "localhost",
      port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
      server: {
        baseDir: ["./", "./dist"]
      }
    })
]
...
```

**Any client-side-page**

```
const socketURL = 'http://localhost:8080' // whatever your socket port
const socket = io(socketURL);

socket.on("someEvent", data => {
    console.log(`I can now do something with ${data}`);
});
```

And the result was all the 404s going away. I'm not 100% sure what was causing it, though clearing down my machine made sure any strangeness from lingering connections was stopped.